# Python Ternary Operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, one-liner

I have the following code:

```
from django_app.models import Model
def func_name():
    name = "name"
    if Model.objects.filter(name=name).count() > 1:
        raise ValidationError("This name already exists.")
    else:
        return name
```

Now I want to turn it into a one-liner. This is what I did:

```
from django_app.models import Model
def func_name():
    name = "name"
    raise ValidationError("This name already exists") if Model.objects.filter(name=name).count() > 1 else return name
```

But this gives me a syntax error.
Is such an implementation possible in Python?

Comment: No, as the syntax error is telling you it is not possible in this case.

Comment: `raise` and `return` are both statements, not expressions, and can't be part of a conditional expression

Comment: What the others said. And, why??

Answer (score 1):

Because it is impossible.
This is the philosophy of Python: readable code.
Your code

```
raise ValidationError("This name already exists") if Model.objects.filter(name=name).count() > 1 else return name
```

will be executed as

```
if Model.objects.filter(name=name).count() > 1:
    raise ValidationError("This name already exists")
else:
    raise (return name)
```

which is not valid

Also you can't avoid this because raise doesn't return any data.